atop is not logging daily
I installed atop on Rocky 9 to monitor CPU spike issues. On 2/8/2024 (2 days ago) I enabled and started atop:
systemctl enable atop
systemctl start atop

Thus, a file was created in /var/log/atop named atop_20240802.
journalctl -u atop output:
Aug 02 23:52:01 systemd[1]: Starting Atop advanced performance monitor...
Aug 02 23:52:01 systemd[1]: Started Atop advanced performance monitor.

I updated the config file /usr/share/atop/atop.daily:
#!/usr/bin/sh

LOGOPTS=""                              # default options
LOGINTERVAL=3600                        # default interval in seconds
LOGGENERATIONS=7                        # default number of days
LOGPATH=/var/log/atop                   # default log location

# allow administrator to overrule the variables
# defined above
#
DEFAULTSFILE=/etc/sysconfig/atop                # possibility to overrule vars

ls -ld /var/log/atop/ output:
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 53 Aug  2 23:53 /var/log/atop/

Daily logs were not created for yesterday and today. How to fix it?

Your journalctl command confirms for you that systemd started the atop process.  What command have you invoked that shows you that atop is still running?

@SottoVoce systemctl status atop outputs: atop.service - Atop advanced performance monitor      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/atop.service; enabled; preset: dis      Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-08-02 23:52:01 EEST; 1 day 23h ago        Docs: man:atop(1)    Main PID: 2760523 (atop)       Tasks: 1 (limit: 22585)      Memory: 15.0M         CPU: 10.155s      CGroup: /system.slice/atop.service              └─2760523 /usr/bin/atop -w /var/log/atop/atop_20240802 600

Apart from enabling and starting atop as a background process, also atop-rotate.timer has to be enabled to switch logfiles at midnight:
systemctl enable --now atop-rotate.timer

